# How do I run Get-ACL for HKLM:\Security?

Tags: powershell, automation, registry, acl, regedit

Get-Acl does not pull the Acl for HKLM\Security.

This command works for all other values. When I run get-itemproperty "HKLM:\Security" I get an access denied error, even though I can view both the registry key, and the ACL, manually in regedit.exe. All while running ps as admin.

I tried

get-acl "HKLM:\Security"

The result was blank. Although there are ACL rules configured for System and Administrator that should have been pulled. Why can't I pull the ACL for HKLM\Security, on an account where I have the correct permissions to view it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-Acl path\goes\here` first tries to resolve the target item at `path\goes\here` (equivalent to `Get-Item path\goes\here`), before fetching the associated ACL from the resolved target item.

The default ACL on `HKLM:\SECURITY` is usually configured to **deny** EVERYONE `Read` access - and since deny trumps allow, your admin access doesn't help you :-)

---

One way to work around this - and I'm sure there are other, potentially safer ways - is to use a bit of reflection to hook into the private constructor that `RegistryKey.GetAccessControl()` usually invokes under the hood:

```
# discover private constructor of [RegistrySecurity] class
$registryACLPrivateConstructor = [System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity].GetConstructors([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'NonPublic,Instance')[0]

# prepare arguments - hive, path, and section mask
$hiveHandle = (Get-Item HKLM:\).Handle
$keyPath = 'SECURITY'
$sections = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::All

# construct the ACL by invoking the private ctor
$securityACL = $registryACLPrivateConstructor.Invoke(@($hiveHandle, $keyPath, $sections))
```

`$securityACL` now contains the security descriptor object corresponding to `HKLM:\SECURITY`

Comment: With a little finessing it fits right into what I was working on, thank you. What do you mean 'safer ways', is this a passive script, or does it change a system setting?

Comment: @SeanHenry Great to hear, you're welcome! wrt "safety" I meant in terms of your code working in the future - the private constructor is obviously not part of the public API, so it might change in the future and then you'll find out because the snippet I posted above stops working :)

Comment: Could I leave that whole chunk of code so it always checks for the Private Constructor?

Comment: @SeanHenry That won't help you if it's suddenly no longer there, or its signature changes significantly. It's unlikely to happen, I'm just saying that if it does: tough luck, that's expected :)